# In Java, why the output of int a=('a'+'b'+'c'); are different form System.out.println('a'+'b'+'c'+"")

Tags: java

the original question is like this.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = '1' + '2' + '3' + "";
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

and this gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
```

then I changed the code like this:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = '1' + '2' + '3';
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

the out put is 150.

but when I write my code like this:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println('a'+'b'+'c'+"");
    }
}
```

the output become 294.

I wonder why.

Comment: the difference between 150 and 294 is that you did not sum the same chars ('1', '2', '3' against 'a', 'b', 'c')

Comment: @RC mot a duplicate, doesn't cover what happens when you add a string to it.

Comment: @djechlin, the selected answer, answers it.

Comment: @yunandtidus it's far too dense / lengthy for this question. There is a lot of value to add with a concise answer to this question. I upvoted the concise answer below even though it's slightly incomplete.

Comment: @yunandtidus e.g. why is int x = 'a' + 'b' + 'c' + "" bad but System.out.println('a' + 'b' + 'c' + "") good? It's a diverse question but I certainly don't want to punish the OP for doing more research, and a good answer really should cover it.

Comment: @djechlin, i agree on the string concatenation, but the root of the problem and it's java specification are far better explained in the possible duplicate link

Comment: @yunandtidus right, and this question needs to be actually open to garner a better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The first one does not compile, because you concatenate a String at the end which cause the value to be a String which can't be converted directly to int.
- The output of the second one is 150, because ASCII value for character 1,2,3 are 49,50,51 which return 150 when doing the addition.
- The output of the last one is 294, because you are doing an addition of char values in the ASCII table (97+98+99)

You can verify the values [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) for a,b and c (or any other character).

**Edit :** To explain why the last one output the correct value instead of throwing an error, you first sum all the values as explained before, then convert it to a String adding "" to the sum of the ASCII values of the chars. However, the println method expect a String which is why it does not throw any error.

The first one would work if you would do `Integer.parseInt('1' + '2' + '3' + "");`

Answer (score 3):

When you do this

```
int i = '1' + '2' + '3';
```

the JVM sums the ASCII codes of the given numbers. The result is **150**.

When you add the empty `String`, you are trying to sum an `int`/`char` with a `String`. This is not possible. You can implicitly convert `char` to `int` and vice versa because they are primitive types. You cannot do this with `String` objects because they are not primitives but references. That's why you get an error.

When you do the `println` the primitive values are firstly summed and the automatically **boxed** into reference type so the sum is boxed into a `Character` object. The empty `String` is converted to a `Character` and then is added to the first one. So the result is a `Character` object that has an ASCII code 294. Then the `toString` method of the `Character` is called because that's what the `println(Object)` method does. And the result is **294**

I hope this will help you to understand what is happening :)

Comment: I think this answer catches the actual situation, plus I learned something. (Plus it firmly shows the question is not a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1):

The first is impossible because you can't convert `String` to `int` this way.

The second works because `char`s are kind of numbers, so adding `char`s is adding the numbers they really are. Char `'1'` is the number 49 (see ASCII table), so the sum is 49+50+51 which is 150.

The third works this way because `+` is a left parenthesized operator, which means that `'a'+'b'+'c'+""` should be read as `(('a'+'b')+'c')+""`. `'a'` has ASCII code 97, so you have `294+""`. Then Java knows that is should convert the value to a `String` to be able to catenate the two strings. At the end you have the the string `294`. Modify your last code to the following `System.out.println('a'+'b'+('c'+""));` and you will see that the result will be `195c`.

You must note that `System.out.println` is a method that is used to convert values (of different types) to their `String` representation. This is always possible as every `int` can be converted to a `String` representation of it, but not the converse; not every `String` is a representation of an `int` (so Java will not let you do it so simply).

Answer (score 1):

First: [int i = '1' + '2' + '3' + "";]
If you concat an empty string value, you convert it to a String object, and then String objects can't convert to int.

Second: [int i = '1' + '2' + '3';]
The binary arithmetic operations on char promote to int. It's equal to:
[int i = 49 + 50 + 51] - total: 150.

Third: [System.out.println('a'+'b'+'c'+"");]
At this case you convert 'a' + 'b' + 'c' (that is 294) to String (+"") and then print the result  like a String value and that works ok.